# Data.table assignment with subsetting dt[, x[.N] := z, y]

Tags: r, data.table

I have some data.table:

```
dt <- data.table(smth = 1:6, type = rep(c("cat", "dog"), each = 3))
dt
   smth type
1:    1  cat
2:    2  cat
3:    3  cat
4:    4  dog
5:    5  dog
6:    6  dog
```

I want to do some transformation to it:

```
dt[,  smth := c(smth[1:2], max(smth[1:2])), type]
dt
   smth type
1:    1  cat
2:    2  cat
3:    2  cat
4:    4  dog
5:    5  dog
6:    5  dog
# Could also do this
dt[1:nrow(dt) %% 3 == 0, smth := dt[,  max(smth[1:2]), type]$V1]
```

It would be cleaner if I could do something like

```
dt[,  smth[3] := max(smth[1:2]), type] # Results in error
```

**My question**

Is assignment of the type I have imagined possible? If no: what would be a cleaner way (sticking to data.table) to do what I've done?

Comment: Does, it always have only 3 rows per group?

Comment: Yes, I think we can assume that for my purposes. More generally, .N or b:.N, where b is some integer.

Comment: Re first question, the answer, is no, it is currently impossible. I also tried this many times.

Comment: Eitherway, I think you could do something like `N <- 3 ; dt[, smth := replace(smth, N, max(smth[-N])), by = type]` which looks a bit more readable to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, for the special case of assigning to the first or last value per group, you can use an update join with `mult=`:

```
# Make a table containing the values you want to assign
mdt = dt[, .(msm = max(smth[-.N])), by=type]

# Update join
dt[mdt, on=.(type), mult="last", smth := i.msm]

   smth type
1:    1  cat
2:    2  cat
3:    2  cat
4:    4  dog
5:    5  dog
6:    5  dog
```

For more general assignment to subsets, there's an [open FR](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/571).